# Conditional Permalink based on category?

Tags: permalinks, htaccess

There have been unanswered questions about this here and in the WordPress support forum.

Is it possible to have a conditional Permalink structure for all posts in a category?

for example, `%year%/%category%/postname%` for a given category, but for the other permalinks have a different structure (without the year for example)?

I'm not very efficient with htaccess, I can use some help please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering My own question..**

That was easier than I though.. I used the `post_link` filter to modify the permalink in the following way..

```
function custom_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    // Get the categories for the post
    $post       = get_post( $post_id );
    $category   = get_the_category( $post_id ); 
    $post_year  = mysql2date("Y", $post->post_date);
    $target_cat = 6; // Category we'd like to change permalink for

    if ( empty( $post_year ) ) return $permalink;

    if ( $category[0]->cat_ID == $target_cat ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url( $category[0]->slug . '/' .$post_year .'/' . $post->post_name . '/'  ) );
    }

    return $permalink;
}

add_filter( 'post_link', 'custom_permalink', 10, 2 );
```

And of course, flushing permalinks by visiting the settings > permalinks page.